# Parsing XML in C# with variable children structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to parse an XML file with the following structure: **EDITED**

…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<TABLE>
    <COMPO>
          <alim_code> 1000 </alim_code>
          <const_code> 56700 </const_code>
          <teneur> 0 </teneur>
          <min missing=" " />
          <max missing=" " />
          <code_confiance> D </code_confiance>
          <source_code missing="." />
    </COMPO>
    <COMPO>
          <alim_code> 1000 </alim_code>
          <const_code> 60000 </const_code>
          <teneur> 37,5 </teneur>
          <min>         37,3 </min>
          <max>         37,6 </max>
          <code_confiance> D </code_confiance>
          <source_code> 38 </source_code>
    </COMPO>
</TABLE>
```

…

As you can see several fields are described differently when the value is known or missing. I have tried to use ReadXml() in a DataSet but it does not seems to work on "variable structure". 
Looks like the solution is probably to use Xdocument and LINQ but I am ignorant about LINQ and I did not succeed to write a working code.

I would appreciate if someone can show me possible code to parse and print (or even better add to a db) the content of this kind of XML file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working solution based on Ehsan-Sajjad proposal :)

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "min")]
public class Min
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "missing")]
    public string Missing { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "max")]
public class Max
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "missing")]
    public string Missing { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "source_code")]
public class Source_code
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "missing")]
    public string Missing { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "COMPO")]
public class COMPO
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "alim_code")]
    public string Alim_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "const_code")]
    public string Const_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "teneur")]
    public string Teneur { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "min")]
    public Min Min { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "max")]
    public Max Max { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "code_confiance")]
    public string Code_confiance { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "source_code")]
    public Source_code Source_code { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TABLE")]
public class TABLE
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "COMPO")]
    public List<COMPO> COMPO { get; set; }
}

private void ReadCompoWithSerializer()
{
    string xmlFile = "test.xml";
    string xml = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TABLE));
    TABLE table = null;
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        table = (TABLE)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Inside Min/Max/Source_code objects Value contains the value when present (in that case Missing is null) otherwise Value is null (in that case Missing contain a string)

---

Working solution based on jdweng proposal

```
public class Compo  {
    public string alim_code { get; set; }
    public string const_code { get; set; }
    public string teneur { get; set; }
    public string min { get; set; }
    public string max { get; set; }
    public string code_confiance { get; set; }
    public string source_code { get; set; }
}

private void ReadCompoWithLinq() {
        const string FILENAME = "test.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

        List<Compo> compos = doc.Descendants("COMPO").Select(x => new Compo()
        {
            alim_code = (string)x.Element("alim_code"),
            const_code = (string)x.Element("const_code"),
            teneur = (string)x.Element("teneur"),
            min = (x.Element("min").Attribute("missing") != null) ? null : (string)x.Element("min"),
            max = (x.Element("max").Attribute("missing") != null) ? null : (string)x.Element("max"),
            code_confiance = (string)x.Element("code_confiance"),
            source_code = (x.Element("source_code").Attribute("missing") != null) ? null : (string)x.Element("source_code"),
        }).ToList();
}
```

The min,max,source_code objects contains the string value when provided (in that case the attribute "missing is used in XML description) otherwise the string value is null.

Answer (score 3):

Linq will not be helpful here. What you can do is create the DTO for your xml using the sample xml that contains all the attributes and nodes which can be returned in the xml.

and then deserialize the xml in to that type.

Your classes would be something like following from the xml above which are being generated:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="min")]
public class Min {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="missing")]
    public string Missing { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="max")]
public class Max {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="missing")]
    public string Missing { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="source_code")]
public class Source_code {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="missing")]
    public string Missing { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="COMPO")]
public class COMPO {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="alim_code")]
    public string Alim_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="const_code")]
    public string Const_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="teneur")]
    public string Teneur { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="min")]
    public Min Min { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="max")]
    public Max Max { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="code_confiance")]
    public string Code_confiance { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="source_code")]
    public Source_code Source_code { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `XmlSerializer class to deserialize it :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<COMPO>));
List<COMPO> compos = null;
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
   compos = (List<COMPO>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

### EDIT:

In that case add another type for `Table` which would be :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Table")]
public class Table {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="COMPO")]
    public List<COMPO> COMPO { get; set; }
}
```

and now the adjust the de-serialization code accordingly:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Table));
Table table = null;
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
   compos = (Table)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code but I get an exception. This is probably due to the fact that I did not mention that the COMPO blocks are inside a <TABLE> </TABLE> block in the XML  file

Comment: you can use http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to generate the c# classes against your xml

Comment: I have added the Table class (created using the link you provided) and modified the reader but I am still getting an exception error in the document XML(1,1). Invalid data at the root level line 1 position 1 (this is an approximate translation!). The file comes from https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/table-de-composition-nutritionnelle-des-aliments-ciqual/#_ compo_2017 11 21.xml

Comment: make sure the xml is valid, the errot seems to be due to xml format

Comment: It looks like the code you provided can handle the XML structure when the "missing" field is present but not the other form. so <min missing=" " /> works but not <min>  37,3 </min>. Therefore this solution does not work for my problem.

Comment: that should not be the case, it will map only those properties that are avaialble

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake. I was calling StringReader() with the xmlFileName. After passing it the content returned by File.ReadAllText() it now works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @DrCoolZic don't forget to mark it answer if it helped you :)

Comment: In fact I still cant get the the min and max values. When the attribute "missing" is used the Min class contains the missing field with content = " " and when missing is not there then missing field is null. This is OK. However there is no way to get the min value (for example 37.3 in second entry of the provided example). I am not sure that [XmlElement(ElementName = "min")]  public Min Min { get; set; } really mean something. Under the debugger Min only contains a missing field that can be null or contains the string but there is no place to store the min value ???

Comment: @DrCoolZic can you create a demo fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I do not understand your request "demo fiddle"? Do you want me to publish the code I am using? As a test case I am using the very simple XML file shown in the question. Again the problem with your solution is that there is no place to store the min/max values when provided? Or am I missing something? The Min and Max classes only have one "missing" field but no place to store value

Answer (score 1):

I would use Xml Linq.  There are some items that can be null that you need to handle properly.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            List<Compo> compos = doc.Descendants("COMPO").Select(x => new Compo() {
                alim_code = (int?)x.Element("alim_code"),
                const_code = (int?)x.Element("const_code"),
                teneur =  (string)x.Element("teneur") == "" ? null : (decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal((string) x.Element("teneur"),provider),
                min = (string)x.Element("min") == "" ? null : (decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal((string) x.Element("teneur"),provider),
                max = (string)x.Element("max") == "" ? null : (decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal((string) x.Element("teneur"),provider),
                code_confiance = (string)x.Element("code_confiance"),
                source_code = (string)x.Element("source_code") == "" ? null : (int?)int.Parse(((string)x.Element("source_code")).Trim())
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Compo
    {
        public int? alim_code {get; set;}
        public int? const_code {get; set;}
        public decimal? teneur {get; set;}
        public decimal? min {get; set;}
        public decimal? max {get; set;}
        public string code_confiance {get; set;}
        public int? source_code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have hard time understanding this Linq code. Can you please modify to add the TABLE root element that I have added in the description. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a Table. class? All you need is a List<Compo>.  The linq Descendants() method does not need the full path, just the element name.

Comment: tried your code but I am getting an exception with message: The format of the input string is incorrect but I have no idea what that mean.

Comment: I made changes to handle the empty elements.

Comment: OK I got the idea. I will test with more appropriate types and I will let you know. Thanks